# How to switch from root to user in Ubuntu running in Termux?

Tags: sudo, root, su, adduser

I recently installed Ubuntu via Termux on my android phone.

This version is specified when I enter the username and password.
`Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2`

I once went from root to user mode by adduser

`root@localhost:~# <USER>@localhost:~#`

But now I do not know how to switch to this mode again.

How to switch from `root@localhost:~#` to `<USER>@localhost:~#`

Comment: Open terminal and type `exit`. Also don't login with your root login credentials login with your user in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To switch to an user with username `john`, enter the command

```
su john
```

And the prompt would change from `#` to `$` (root to ordinary user).

To get back to root, type `exit`.